# Trying to install aws-sam-cli through brew on ubuntu using "brew tap aws/tap" command ,getting error "fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision"

Tags: homebrew

just installed homebrew , brew --version gives below output

Homebrew 2.7.7
Homebrew/linuxbrew-core (no Git repository)

i have git version 2.27.0 installed , now im trying to run "brew tap aws/tap" command but getting the error "fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision".

im using ubuntu version 20.04

Answer (score 0):

`git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master` - this worked for me

Reference this issue - [Installing upx with Mac Big Sur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66282264/installing-upx-with-mac-big-sur)