# Installing upx with Mac Big Sur

Tags: macos, homebrew, upx

I'm having trouble installing upx. The following are the steps that I took. My macOs is 11.2.1

```
 % ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
==> Checking for `sudo` access (which may request your password).
==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew
==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R vuduc:admin /usr/local/Homebrew
==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
HEAD is now at 3ff5795ae Merge pull request #10652 from danielnachun/revert-gcc-linkage-fix
==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
  https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
  https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

==> Next steps:
- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation: 
    https://docs.brew.sh

% brew install upx
Updating Homebrew...
fatal: Could not resolve HEAD to a revision
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "upx".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

How can I solve this issue? I need to install upx because some apps show "You do not have permission to open the application…" when I tried to run them.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I searched for ages and tried various things.

In the end, I resolved it getting relevant info from the HomeBrew github and posted it on the UPX GitHub issue log.

Check it out > https://github.com/upx/upx/issues/469

In your preferred Shell (bash / zsh / fish / etc), run this:

```
git -C $(brew --repo homebrew/core) checkout master
```

That will swich your brew from the "origin" branch to the "master" branch

From there, run this:
`brew install upx`